# Yarn can't find private Github npm registry

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg

I signed up for the Github private npm registry beta and followed their instruction: https://github.com/features/package-registry

Works great with npm but I'd prefer using yarn. And while npm has no issues finding the registered package, yarn can't find it at all.

`yarn add @omniphx/adminite-adminite-ui-components` outputs:

```
yarn add v1.19.0
info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "@omniphx/adminite-ui-components" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

After reading up on private repos with yarn, I thought the trick was due to yarn having a slightly different rc format. Unfortunately, that didn't work either and yarn is still unable to find the private registry.

**.npmrc**

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@omniphx:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/omniphx
```

**.yarnrc**

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
"@omniphx:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com/omniphx"
```

Also confirmed that my github token is set too with `yarn config list`:

```
yarn config v1.19.0
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.19.0 npm/? node/v12.11.1 darwin x64',
  email: 'mattjmitchener@gmail.com',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1570679687836,
  username: 'omniphx',
  '@omniphx:registry': 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/omniphx'
}
info npm config
{
  '//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken': 'fake12345',
  registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org',
  '@omniphx:registry': 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/omniphx',
  python: '/usr/bin/python'
}
```

Any idea?

---

**Resolved**

```
Changed "@myorg:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com/myorg"
To      "@myorg:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

Comment: Does this fix help in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430182/how-do-i-install-private-packages-using-yarn-inside-a-github-action/58430650#58430650

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've just run into a similar situation. It seemed that `yarn` was only looking in the main Yarn package registry for my organization's private package. I had copied the examples from GitHub's Packages documentation for constructing your `.npmrc` file directly to the `.yarnrc` file in the project that will be consuming the app, not knowing that the formats were different (I've never had to deal with `.yarnrc` files before).

However, after updating the `.yarnrc` file with the correct format that you've mentioned above (which I also found in googling around), `yarn` successfully found the private package and installed it correctly.

As a heads up, my `yarn` version: **1.17.3**

### Steps I Took

1. Start new terminal session
2. `cd` to the project
3. `nvm use` (if you have a specific node version to use)
4. Add the correctly-formatted `.yarnrc` file to the project. See below for what it looks like.
5. Manually add the package and version range to the `package.json` for my private package
6. Run `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@MyOrg`

   - See the note below on scope / org gotcha's
7. Run `yarn`

That worked for me.

#### .yarnrc

```
"@myorg:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

**Note**: See below for a note on the org / scope name gotcha's

#### Other Notes

I know that it appears that you don't have any issues with this, given your GH username / scope above, but for anyone else that comes here, the documentation on GH is a little sparse with regards to mapping your username / org name to a scope in the package name. Just remember these little gotcha's here:

- The name of your package must always be scoped to your org (or username)

  - E.g., `name: @johndturn/my-package`
- If your organization has capital letters in it, like `MyOrg`, just replace them in the name of the package in your `package.json` **and** your `.yarnrc` with lowercase

  - E.g., `name: @myorg/my-package`
  - **Note**: When authenticating with `npm login`, I still have kept the uppercase letters in the `--scope=` argument.
- The name of your package doesn't have to be the same name of the repo.

  - E.g., for a repo called `MyOrg/random-prefix.js-lib`, you can have `name: @myorg/js-lib` in your `package.json` file for the project itself. Then, installing it in other projects will look something like `@myorg/js-lib: 1.0.0`.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks. Now figuring out how to set it in my CI, which does not run on Github Actions but rather on jenkins.

Comment: @DhwaneetBhatt great question, and it should be fairly straightforward, with some assumptions. If you're running in Jenkins with Pipelines and a `Jenkinsfile`, **my assumption** is that you can simply add in the above commands (like `npm login ...`) into your `Jenkinsfile`, in a pre-build step. This also assumes that you have Jenkins authenticated with some sort of user in your GitHub org that has the correct privileges to pull packages from your org. That said, I haven't implemented it for our Jenkins boxes yet, but I'll let you know when I do (if it varies from what I've mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looks like my issue was that I had `"@myorg:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com/myorg"` instead of `"@myorg:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"`. Weird that that same url worked fine in my `.npmrc`

Comment: @MatthewMitchener looks like you found the simplest answer: just leave the `/myorg` off the end in your `.npmrc`, and then GitHub Package Registry works with either yarn or npm. (With no need for a separate `.yarnrc`.)

Answer (score 7):

In Yarn v2+ the setup has changed quite a bit. ".yarnrc" is ignored and only ".yarnrc.yml" is used.

To setup a private registry with a scope and token from env, add something along these lines to the ".yarnrc.yml" file (fontawesome example):

```
npmScopes:
  fortawesome:
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.fontawesome.com"
    npmAuthToken: ${FONTAWESOME_TOKEN}
```

Documentation: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmScopes

Answer (score 6):

The problem I had is slightly different.

After tried what John suggested I still can't add private registry packages with `yarn` (but perfectly fine with `npm`)

Then I realise two things:

For GitHub packages, `npm` is fine with either

`registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/my-org`

or

`@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

but `yarn` only allow the latter syntax.

Docs from Github website only show the first syntax which could cause problems for yarn users.

Another thing is that if you `npm login` to the private registry but use a `.yarnrc` file in your project, yarn can't really mix your `npm` credentials with it. Although it seems behave differently on different environment.

But it would seems to be a best practice to stick with either `yarn login` + `.yarnrc`, or `npm login` + `.npmrc` (you can still use yarn to manage your packages in both cases)

Comment: As to the two different formats, this Github blog post explains the migration: https://github.blog/2019-09-11-proxying-packages-with-github-package-registry-and-other-updates/ 
The `registry=` format enabled proxying of all npm packages via the github packages registry, whereas `@my-org:registry:` would lock down the requests to only the github packages registry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with npm/yarn so I might be misunderstanding what is happening here, but I don't think package proxying from the npm registry works with yarn yet. Could that be related? When package proxying was released for npm I remember reading comments on Twitter from people that tried it with yarn and it didn't work.

Found the Twitter thread here:
https://twitter.com/github/status/1171832034580451328

> It doesn't work with Yarn. As soon as I change the registry url -> Couldn't find package.