# How do I install private packages using yarn inside a Github Action?

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg, github-actions

My current workflow:

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install yarn -g
          yarn
          yarn test
        env:
          CI: true
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

I have setup my `NPM_TOKEN` in the repo secrets area.

The token is also in use on Netlify, and the netlify build process works.

When this workflow runs, I get a 404 for any of my private packages.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Found a fix:

Write out `.npmrc` as part of the job instead of relying on an env variable.

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" > .npmrc
          npm install yarn -g
          yarn
          yarn test
        env:
          CI: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following question/answer might be related.

[Yarn can't find private Github npm registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316109/yarn-cant-find-private-github-npm-registry/58317811#58317811)

If this is the same issue, package proxying from the npm registry doesn't work with yarn yet.

Comment: what is the workaround for yarn users then?  is there no way to use GH package registry with yarn?

Comment: I don't know a lot about npm/yarn so I'm honesty not sure. Does the workaround posted by @guy-bowden not work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an existing `.npmrc` and ONLY want to append the token into the existing file instead of overwriting it, this worked for me.

*** NOTE: The `echo` includes a `-e` argument and a `\n` in order to prepend a newline. Also instead of `>` which overwrites the `.npmrc` file there is a `>>` which appends to the `.npmrc` file.

```yaml
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          echo -e "\n//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc
          npm install yarn
          yarn
          yarn test
        env:
          CI: true
```