# Netlify and yarn not finding Github package

Tags: yarnpkg, netlify, github-package-registry

I'm building a site with yarn and hosting it on Netlify. I want to integrate another repo as a package, but I'd rather not put that package on the npm registry because it's very limited use. I hosted the [package publicly via GitHub here](https://github.com/ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization/packages/873560) and added it to my `package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization": "^1.0.0",
    .
    .
    .
   }
```

I can build the site locally and everything runs fine. However, when I deploy to Netlify, I get the following error:

```
10:38:06 PM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
10:38:06 PM: error Couldn't find package "@ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
10:38:06 PM: Error during Yarn install
```

I've created a `.yarnrc` file as follows and added it to the root of my project:

```
@ourjapanlife:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

I've researched this a lot, but most of the advice relates to [private GitHub repos](https://github.community/t/netlify-getting-401-from-github-package-registry-with-auth-token/16415). I'm fine with this package being public, but I don't want it centrally hosted because it's just some i18n files of little use to the wider community. [This answer also looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328063/1860768), but switching from `.npmrc` to `.yarnrc` did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

A collaborator helped me resolve this by running:

```
yarn add https://github.com/ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization
```

And the resulting entry in `package.json` looks like this:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization": "https://github.com/ourjapanlife/findadoc-localization",
    .
    .
    .
   }
```

At this point I could delete the `.npmrc` / `.yarnrc` and remove the `prenetlify` step.

It builds successfully on Netlify and resolved to the latest package via `yarn.lock`.

It turns out in experimenting, I had switched between the npm and github registries and manually edited package.json. It's better to re-install via the command line.